# Android bluetooth low energy characteristic value

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have this code on android app that I have edited but I'm having a problem on getting the characteristic value to set on `mHumidity` (`TextView`). the value being display is something like `android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt@4780c` something like that. But my expected value is 0 or 1 from a button pushed on my BLE device

```
/**
 * Created by Dave Smith
 * Double Encore, Inc.
 * MainActivity
 */
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback {
        private static final String TAG = "BluetoothGattActivity";

        private static final String DEVICE_NAME = "Light";

        /* Humidity Service */
        private static final UUID HUMIDITY_SERVICE = UUID.fromString("29e70001-9227-e097-3473-09a5cc69a43a");
        private static final UUID HUMIDITY_DATA_CHAR = UUID.fromString("29e70002-9227-e097-3473-09a5cc69a43a");
        private static final UUID HUMIDITY_CONFIG_CHAR = UUID.fromString("29e70003-9227-e097-3473-09a5cc69a43a");

        /* Client Configuration Descriptor */
        private static final UUID CONFIG_DESCRIPTOR = UUID.fromString("00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");


    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private SparseArray<BluetoothDevice> mDevices;

    private BluetoothGatt mConnectedGatt;

    private TextView mTemperature, mHumidity, mPressure;

    private ProgressDialog mProgress;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setProgressBarIndeterminate(true);
        /*
         * We are going to display the results in some text fields
         */
    //    mTemperature = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_temperature);
        mHumidity = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_humidity);
    //    mPressure = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_pressure);
        /*
         * Bluetooth in Android 4.3 is accessed via the BluetoothManager, rather than
         * the old static BluetoothAdapter.getInstance()
         */
        BluetoothManager manager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        mBluetoothAdapter = manager.getAdapter();

        mDevices = new SparseArray<BluetoothDevice>();

        /*
         * A progress dialog will be needed while the connection process is
         * taking place
         */
        mProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mProgress.setIndeterminate(true);
        mProgress.setCancelable(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        /*
         * We need to enforce that Bluetooth is first enabled, and take the
         * user to settings to enable it if they have not done so.
         */
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || !mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            //Bluetooth is disabled
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivity(enableBtIntent);
            finish();
            return;
        }

        /*
         * Check for Bluetooth LE Support.  In production, our manifest entry will keep this
         * from installing on these devices, but this will allow test devices or other
         * sideloads to report whether or not the feature exists.
         */
        if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No LE Support.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
            return;
        }

        clearDisplayValues();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        //Make sure dialog is hidden
        mProgress.dismiss();
        //Cancel any scans in progress
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mStopRunnable);
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mStartRunnable);
        mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        //Disconnect from any active tag connection
        if (mConnectedGatt != null) {
            mConnectedGatt.disconnect();
            mConnectedGatt = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Add the "scan" option to the menu
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        //Add any device elements we've discovered to the overflow menu
        for (int i=0; i < mDevices.size(); i++) {
            BluetoothDevice device = mDevices.valueAt(i);
            menu.add(0, mDevices.keyAt(i), 0, device.getName());
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_scan:
                mDevices.clear();
                startScan();
                return true;
            default:
                //Obtain the discovered device to connect with
                BluetoothDevice device = mDevices.get(item.getItemId());
                Log.i(TAG, "Connecting to "+device.getName());
                /*
                 * Make a connection with the device using the special LE-specific
                 * connectGatt() method, passing in a callback for GATT events
                 */
                mConnectedGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, mGattCallback);
                //Display progress UI
                mHandler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(null, MSG_PROGRESS, "Connecting to "+device.getName()+"..."));
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private void clearDisplayValues() {
        //mTemperature.setText("---");
        mHumidity.setText("---");

    }


    private Runnable mStopRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            stopScan();
        }
    };
    private Runnable mStartRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            startScan();
        }
    };

    private void startScan() {
        mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(this);
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

        mHandler.postDelayed(mStopRunnable, 2500);
    }

    private void stopScan() {
        mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(this);
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
    }

    /* BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback */

    @Override
    public void onLeScan(BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
        Log.i(TAG, "New LE Device: " + device.getName() + " @ " + rssi);
        /*
         * We are looking for SensorTag devices only, so validate the name
         * that each device reports before adding it to our collection
         */
        if (DEVICE_NAME.equals(device.getName())) {
            mDevices.put(device.hashCode(), device);
            //Update the overflow menu
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    }

    /*
     * In this callback, we've created a bit of a state machine to enforce that only
     * one characteristic be read or written at a time until all of our sensors
     * are enabled and we are registered to get notifications.
     */

    private BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {


        private void readNextSensor(BluetoothGatt gatt) {
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic;
                   Log.d(TAG, "Reading humidity");
                    characteristic = gatt.getService(HUMIDITY_SERVICE).getCharacteristic(HUMIDITY_DATA_CHAR);
            mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_DISMISS);
            Log.i(TAG, "All Sensors Enabled");
            gatt.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
        }

        /*
         * Enable notification of changes on the data characteristic for each sensor
         * by writing the ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE flag to that characteristic's
         * configuration descriptor.
         */
        private void setNotifyNextSensor(BluetoothGatt gatt) {
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic;
                    Log.d(TAG, "Set notify humidity");
                    characteristic = gatt.getService(HUMIDITY_SERVICE).getCharacteristic(HUMIDITY_DATA_CHAR);
            mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_DISMISS);
            Log.i(TAG, "All Sensors Enabled");
            //Enable local notifications
            gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true);
            //Enabled remote notifications
            BluetoothGattDescriptor desc = characteristic.getDescriptor(CONFIG_DESCRIPTOR);
            desc.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
            gatt.writeDescriptor(desc);
        }



        /* OK */

        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Connection State Change: "+status+" -> "+connectionState(newState));
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS && newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                /*
                 * Once successfully connected, we must next discover all the services on the
                 * device before we can read and write their characteristics.
                 */
                gatt.discoverServices();
                mHandler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(null, MSG_PROGRESS, "Discovering Services..."));
            } else if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS && newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                /*
                 * If at any point we disconnect, send a message to clear the weather values
                 * out of the UI
                 */
                mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_CLEAR);
            } else if (status != BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                /*
                 * If there is a failure at any stage, simply disconnect
                 */
                gatt.disconnect();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Services Discovered: "+status);
            mHandler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(null, MSG_PROGRESS, "Enabling Sensors..."));
            /*
             * With services discovered, we are going to reset our state machine and start
             * working through the sensors we need to enable
            */
         //  enableNextSensor(gatt);
        readNextSensor(gatt);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
            //For each read, pass the data up to the UI thread to update the display
            if (HUMIDITY_DATA_CHAR.equals(characteristic.getUuid())) {
                mHandler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(null, MSG_HUMIDITY, characteristic));
            }

            //After reading the initial value, next we enable notifications
            setNotifyNextSensor(gatt);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
            //After writing the enable flag, next we read the initial value
            readNextSensor(gatt);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
            /*
             * After notifications are enabled, all updates from the device on characteristic
             * value changes will be posted here.  Similar to read, we hand these up to the
             * UI thread to update the display.
             */

            if (HUMIDITY_DATA_CHAR.equals(characteristic.getUuid())) {
                mHandler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(null, MSG_HUMIDITY, characteristic));
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onDescriptorWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor, int status) {
            //Once notifications are enabled, we move to the next sensor and start over with enable

             readNextSensor(gatt);
        }

        @Override
        public void onReadRemoteRssi(BluetoothGatt gatt, int rssi, int status) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Remote RSSI: "+rssi);
        }

        private String connectionState(int status) {
            switch (status) {
                case BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED:
                    return "Connected";
                case BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED:
                    return "Disconnected";
                case BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTING:
                    return "Connecting";
                case BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTING:
                    return "Disconnecting";
                default:
                    return String.valueOf(status);
            }
        }
    };

    /*
     * We have a Handler to process event results on the main thread
     */
    private static final int MSG_HUMIDITY = 101;
    private static final int MSG_PROGRESS = 201;
    private static final int MSG_DISMISS = 202;
    private static final int MSG_CLEAR = 301;
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic;
            switch (msg.what) {
                case MSG_HUMIDITY:
                    characteristic = (BluetoothGattCharacteristic) msg.obj;
                    if (characteristic.getValue() == null) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "Error obtaining humidity value");
                        return;
                    }
                    updateHumidityValues(characteristic);
                    break;
                case MSG_PROGRESS:
                    mProgress.setMessage((String) msg.obj);
                    if (!mProgress.isShowing()) {
                        mProgress.show();
                    }
                    break;
                case MSG_DISMISS:
                    mProgress.hide();
                    break;
                case MSG_CLEAR:
                    clearDisplayValues();
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    /* Methods to extract sensor data and update the UI */

    private void updateHumidityValues(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {

        mHumidity.setText(String.valueOf(characteristic));

    }
}
//         double humidity = SensorTagData.extractHumidity(characteristic);
//         mHumidity.setText(String.format("%.0f%%", humidity));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of the characteristic is a `byte[]` and not a String. When you do String.valueOf(characteristic) you print the object name and reference on the heap, not the actual value.

What you have to do is byte convert the array into something useful. This is very dependent on the BLE Service and its accompanying characteristic. But lets say that it is just one byte with a value.

```
/* Methods to extract sensor data and update the UI */

private void updateHumidityValues(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
    short lsb = characteristic.getValue()[0] & 0xff;
    mHumidity.setText(String.valueOf(lsb));

}
```

Comment: Sorry for such a silly question, but how will look this one in case of 2 bytes ?
... getValue()[0] & 0xff;

Comment: I think you are trying to get a **short** whereas your evaluation returns an **int**.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use `characteristic.getValue()` to print the characteristic value.

**i.e.**

```
mHumidity.setText(String.valueOf(characteristic.getValue()));
```

And this is a cached value to get the latest value you may need to call readCharacteristic(characteristic).

**Please refer this page for more details:** https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCharacteristic.html

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
characteristic.getProperties()
```

This will tell you how to get your value more directly.
For example, if your Property required a float, you can use

```
float char_float_value = characteristic.getFloatValue(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_FLOAT,1);
```

This would give you the float value of the characteristic.
You just need the getProperties() int value and then get the corrresponding FORMAT (Float, int (multiple), string)